# How to flip char array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

We can flip Matrix in matlab using **fliplr** function but what if I want to flip the char matrix

```
    XOX.
    XOXX
    OXXX
    XOXO
```

I want to flip this matrix so that each row got reversed, just as happened in the case of fliplr in numeric matrix.

Comment: You really should have at least tried this first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your input is a `char` array, `fliplr` should still work, for example:

```
a=['a11';'1a1';'11a']

fliplr(a)
ans =
11a  
1a1
a11
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply fliplr to each cell:

```
C = {'A';'rolling';'stone';'gathers';'momentum.'}
a = cellfun(@(x) fliplr(x), C,  'UniformOutput', false)

>> a

a = 

    'A'
    'gnillor'
    'enots'
    'srehtag'
    '.mutnemom'
```